# Bootstrap Grid Layout on Mobile Devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-images

I am trying to create a Bootstrap grid layout with different images.  Everything is fine except when viewing on different mobile devices in the mobile inspector on Chrome. Below is a picture of what it looks like in the inspector.  The second image is slightly off-centered from the former image.

[image: Inspector]

```
<section class="container" id="main">
<section class="center-block text-center">
    <h4>Random Column Number 1</h4>
    <img src="https://www.apple.com/ac/structured-data/images/open_graph_logo.png?201701231950" width="500px" height="262px"/>
</section>
<section class="col-lg-6 center-block text-center">
    <h4>Random Column Number 2</h4>
    <img src="http://www.appliste.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Apple_1998.png" width="500px" height="262px" />
</section>
<section class="col-lg-6 center-block text-center">
<h4>Random Column Number 3</h4>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/Apple_Computer_Logo_rainbow.svg/931px-Apple_Computer_Logo_rainbow.svg.png" width="500px" height="262px" />
  </section>
</section>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xgnw2e9g/2/). The problem is that I am trying to off-set the second section as a "col-lg-6 center-block text-center" class.  If I remove the col-lg-6 it works just fine.  But I want to be able to stack two images next to each other.  Is there any way to correct this so that it is centered like the first image?  The JSFiddle contains three images.

This is what it looks like at full screen.
[image: Full screen image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images are not the correct aspect ratio because of the force width and height set. Perhaps just set a max-height so they image width can change responsively.

Also, `center-block` should be used on the images instead of the `col-`

```
<section class="container" id="main">
  <section class="center-block text-center">
    <h4>Random Column Number 1</h4>
    <img src="https://www.apple.com/ac/structured-data/images/open_graph_logo.png?201701231950" class="center-block img-responsive" />
  </section>
  <section class="col-lg-6 text-center">
    <h4>Random Column Number 2</h4>
    <img src="http://www.appliste.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Apple_1998.png" class="center-block img-responsive" />
  </section>
  <section class="col-lg-6 center-block text-center">
    <h4>Random Column Number 3</h4>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/Apple_Computer_Logo_rainbow.svg/931px-Apple_Computer_Logo_rainbow.svg.png" class="center-block img-responsive" />
  </section>
</section>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/JBhTWnvfv5

Comment: This does work, yes, but I would like to keep the images the same size if possible.

Comment: The first image is larger than the others because it is not restricted to a column size.

Comment: You can still set width/height on the img, they'll just be out of proportion. The centering issue was due to `center-block` not being on the image.

Comment: Removing the image-responsive tag resets it back to the way it was.  I left the `center-block` tag.

Comment: The `col-lg-6 center-block` tag is what is causing the problem, but I want to keep it for the full screen layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-sm-3">....</div>
```

....

use this code in your div where you are placing your grid and and div with these classes as i mentioned above. It works

Comment: That does not fix the issue.  It is still off-center in the inspector. I am doing <secion class="col-sm-3 col-lg-6 center-block text-center">.

Comment: As i said use this in div not in the section. Then you will see your problem will be solved

Comment: That helps but it is forcing all of the images too far to the right rather than centering them.

Comment: Make another div which will be blank add this div to that and in parent div add class="center". you will get rid of this problem.

Comment: Should it look like this? <section class="center"><section class="col-sm-3">...</section></section>

Comment: Nope instead of using section make that to div and also close all the div in the end.

Comment: The distinction between div and section does not matter.  It does the same thing.

Comment: But seeing your requirements it should be in div to use bootstrap grid layout

Answer (score 0):

Just add a media query when on mobile devices.

It would look something like this:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
   .center-block {
        padding:0 !important;
   }
 }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xgnw2e9g/3/)